# Swift avoid website's cookies warning

Tags: ios, swift, url, cookies

I have an app where users can load different urls. The problem is that everytime user load a url, KINWebBrowser shows annoying cookies warnings messages. It's possible in any way to accept automatically those cookies or delete those messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of unwanted elements by running some Javascript on the webpage after it's loaded.

KINWebBrowser defines a `KINWebBrowserDelegate` protocol that calls the method `didFinishLoadingURL` when a page loads, so we run the Javascript from there:

```
func removeClassFromWebpage(browser: KINWebBrowserViewController, className: String) {
  let js = "var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('\(className)');" +
           "while(elements.length > 0) {                                   " +
           "   elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);            " +
           "}                                                              "

  if (browser.uiWebView != nil) { // iOS <9 browser class
    browser.uiWebView!.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(js)
  }
  else if (browser.wkWebView != nil) { // iOS 9 browser class
     browser.wkWebView!.evaluateJavaScript(js, completionHandler: nil)
  }
}

func webBrowser(webBrowser: KINWebBrowserViewController!, didFinishLoadingURL URL: NSURL!) {
  removeClassFromWebpage(browser: webBrowser, className: "cookiePolicy")
  // Replace "cookiePolicy" with whatever the class name of the
  // cookie popup is.
}
```

You'll have to do some sleuthing in the webpage source that your app accesses to figure out what the class name of the cookie popup is.

If you want to take a stab at removing ALL cookie popups, AdBlock Plus has a list of typical cookie popup classes over here: http://www.kiboke-studio.hr/i-dont-care-about-cookies/abp/

You'd have to make a list of cookie-popup classes, and loop through it calling `removeClassFromWebpage` for each one.

Comment: I should put your code in the app delegate.swift file? i've done that, but cookie policy warning is showed the same...

Comment: This code will go in the **delegate** for your KINWebBrowserViewController. [Here's a pretty good introduction to delegates.](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/08/how-delegation-works-a-swift-developer-guide/) What you need to do:    (1)  Add the protocol `KINWebBrowserDelegate` to a class you've already made OR make a new class for it.
(2) Implement my methods above for whatever class is the delegate
(3) Set the KINWebBrowserViewController's **delegate** property to an instance of the delegate class.

Comment: i have 1) added the protocol to my ViewController ok 2) implemented your method 3) how i can set KINWebBrowserViewController's delegate property to an instance of the delegate class? for example ViewController?

Comment: Swift1 did you ever find a solution to this problem?